# What is the meaning of the equation of the change in entropy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy, differentiation, notation

In my chemistry book, the formula for change in entropy is given as :

$$\int{dS} = \int{\frac{δq_{rev}}{T}}$$

What is the meaning of $δq_{rev}$? I know that it is the heat exchanged in a reversible process. But why $δq_{rev}$? Why not $dq_{rev}$? What is the difference between $δq_{rev}$ and $dq_{rev}$? What exactly is the meaning of $δ$ here and how is it different from $d$?

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/619578/what-does-an-elementary-value-delta-of-a-quantity-mean)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between $\Delta$, $d$ and $\delta$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65724/)

Answer (score 3):

$\delta Q$ represents the inexact differential that means a change in heat from one state to another depends on the path.
$$\Delta Q=\int_{\mathcal{P}} \delta Q \not= Q(\text{Final})-Q(\text{Initial})$$

Comment: Oh damn, learn something new everyday. Didn't know that notation before :)

Answer (score 1):

It’s an inexact differential because, unlike properties like internal energy, pressure, temperature etc. heat (like work) is not a property so heat doesn’t “change” . The $\delta$  means *amount* of energy transferred in the form of heat. The amount transferred may then result in a *change* in the properties ($dT$, $dp$, $dU$, etc.) of the entities between which energy is transferred.

Hope this helps